# 3 tables - FK integrity from tb1 bad. tb2 & tb3 are good. tb1 is the main - how do I compare and find out what id are bad in tb2 & tb3

Tags: sql-server

I have brought my data from Salesforce. There is a main table for Cases and it references the Accounts table and Contacts table. The Accounts table and Contacts table are compliant. The Cases table has problems with both the Accounts and Contacts table. I want to clean the data between both that matches and remove the rest to create integrity. I have used below to find what matches. However, I want to know what does not match and if I have Ids that can match them through other routes.

Is there another statement I can use for just what doesn't equal?

```
SELECT Contact.AccountId AS Contact, Account.Id AS Account, [Case].ContactId AS [Case]
FROM Account
INNER JOIN [Case] ON Account.Id = [Case].AccountId
INNER JOIN
Contact ON Account.Id = Contact.AccountId AND [Case].ContactId = Contact.Id AND Account.Id = Contact.AccountId
```

Ultimately I want to create the FK relationships from Case to Account & Contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either do a left join and check for nulls, or use not exists() queries:

```
SELECT Contact.AccountId AS Contact, Account.Id AS Account, [Case].ContactId AS [Case]
FROM Account
left JOIN [Case] ON Account.Id = [Case].AccountId
where case.accountid is null
```

or

```
SELECT Contact.AccountId AS Contact, Account.Id AS Account, [Case].ContactId AS 
[Case]
FROM Account
where not exists(elect * from case where case.accountid=account.id)
```

Comment: That put me on track. I realized I needed to see all of the matches from Case to Account and Case to Contact and compare. I don't know if I went the fastest route, but it gave me the nulls and a single ID that was running rampant  and not making it consistently to other tables. I came up with:
`Select  a.id As AccountId, s.AccountId As CaseAcct, s.ContactId AS CaseCon, c.Id AS Conid, s.CreatedDate
From Contact c full join
[Case] s 
 on s.ContactId = c.Id
  full join Account a
   on a.Id = s.AccountId
    order by CreatedDate desc`

This showed me what was causing the issues.

Comment: Great. The best answers are the ones that don't just give you the code, but point you in the direction to work it out for yourself. Glad to be of help and well done.